Rest client injection fails in Vaadin application running in Quarkus
I have a pretty simple app built in Vaadin/Quarkus that needs to access a REST API, so I am trying to use the @RestClient injection from Quarkus to access it.
My REST client is defined thus:
@Path("/invoices")
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "invoice-service-api")
public interface InvoiceServiceApi {

    @GET
    @Path("/get/{agencyId}/{invoiceId}")
    public Invoice get(@PathParam("agencyId") String agencyId, @PathParam("invoiceId") String invoiceId);

...and my MainView like this:
@Route("/") 
public class MainView extends HorizontalLayout {
    
    private TabSheet tabs;

    private InvoiceServiceApi invoiceService;
    
    public MainView() {
        
        super();
        
        invoiceService = RestClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .baseUri(URI.create("https://my.url.here/foo/"))
            .build(InvoiceServiceApi.class);
        
        tabs = new TabSheet();
        tabs.setWidthFull();
        
        // etc ...
        
    }
}

If I use RestClientBuilder as above, then everything works, but if I change the code to:
@Route("/") 
public class MainView extends HorizontalLayout {
    
    private TabSheet tabs;

    @RestClient
    InvoiceServiceApi invoiceService;
    
    public MainView() {
        
        super();
        
        tabs = new TabSheet();
        tabs.setWidthFull();
        
        // etc ...
        
    }
}

then I get the exception:
 2024-04-04 08:44:16,691 ERROR [com.vaa.flo.rou.InternalServerError] (executor-thread-2) There was an exception while trying to navigate to '': java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.foo.bar.InvoiceServiceApi.list(String, String)" because "this.invoiceService" is null
I'm guessing the problem is something to do with component lifecycle of the beans being different in Vaadin to Quarkus, but I can't find any examples of anyone doing this or any gotchas that suggest a different approach is needed.
Anyone got any suggestions?

that's because MainView is probably not a CDI-bean (annotated with Singleton or ApplicationScoped).

I don't know Quarkus, but with Spring based vaadin projects, any component with a @Route annotation is able to inject beans. If this were spring based, I would have said to try constructor-injection instead of field injection, since field-injected beans are not yet initialized (== null) within the actual constructor. Not sure if this helps, but worth a shot

As I said earlier, MainView is not a CDI-bean so injection is not going to work there. However you can use manual/programmatic CDI lookup:
var restClient = CDI.current().select(InvoiceServiceApi.class, RestClient.LITERAL).get();

Yes, you can do this by writing code, but there should be a pattern to allow injection into the Vaadin view/component hierarchy. This also isn't really delivering on the promise here:
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/integrations/quarkus#vaadin-cdi-features

I'm not familiar with Vaadin. If the Vaadin documentation says that generating a jandex index is the way, then you should try that.

That's just for Vaadin add-ons. I agree with you that the problem could be that the MainView is not a bean, but then I would expect to be able to annotate it in some way that would make sense in this context (perhaps with @RequestScoped) but that also doesn't work.

A further update to this based on trial and error: if I annotate my MainView with @RequestScoped then I can use constructor injection to inject the REST client like:
public MainView(@RestClient InvoiceServiceApi invoiceService) {}
It still does not work via field injection.

You should avoid field injection anyway, constructor injection is the way to go.
